# Proguard and Gson - Convert variable name inside arraylist

Tags: php, android, gson, proguard

In debug, my code works fine.
When I release my apk with proguard 5, Proguard offuscate my variables, and when I try to "Jsonify", the resulting string is offuscated, and so, my PHP script doesn't understand anything.

Here's my code:

ArrayList lCapturas=...;

```
if (lCapturas != null) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type listOfCapturaObject = new TypeToken<List<Captura>>() {
            }.getType();
            json = gson.toJson(lCapturas, listOfCapturaObject);
        }
```

and my Json string

```
[{"j":"2014-09-10 17:35:25","e":"2014-09-  10","f":"19.3641107,-99.1785061","d":28809,"c":85,"b":2705,"a":1,"l":1,"m":0}]
```

I guess I must say Proguard not offuscate Captura Objects.
Is there a way of disabling that option?
Or how should I do???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue :

```
-keep class com.pkg.vo.myClass { *; }
```

for each class I need to keep the variable names.

StackOverflow didn't saved my day :(